# JsonObject extract key and value in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

In kotlin i have a response like that:

```
"nameIdPairs":{"name1":"590f7340a1fc", "name2":"590f7340a1fc"}}
```

since key and value is not determined before, it changes continuosly. Therefore, i cannot use data class. I get this response with JsonObject but i need to extract "name1" and "590f7340a1fc" seperately. What are the possible ways to do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (key in myListTypes.keySet()) {
   myListTypes.get(key).toString()
}
```

works for me!